70's (?) movie about a lost world
I'm trying to identify an old film that I have the vaguest memories of. It's from the Harryhausen ere of stop motion monsters but may have had real lizards in. There are a lot of films that could fit the bill but I remember a particular scene with large dark coloured beasts climbing up the of large structures like pyramids or possibly cliffs. There might have been a scene with a native girl and a large spiderweb too. 

I thought for sure I remembered a scene of two big lumbering dinosaurs somehow walking up a near-vertical wall in "At the Earth's Core", (1976), http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074157/, but the movie is on Youtube and the scene isn't there.  Maybe it's an edited version.  Rubber suits, no stop-motion.

Possibly "Journey to the Centre of the Earth" starring James Mason? Does have a scene with lizards (iguanas?) made out to look like Dimetrodons coming out of canyon walls.

That sounds like it might possibly be The Valley of the Gwangi (1969), which was basically a riff on King Kong featuring a dinosaur instead of an ape. The characters find a valley were prehistoric creatures live and bring one back to star in a rodeo, with disastrous results when it breaks lose. 
